# How to load same classes twice, one using namespace[STRIPE]

Tags: php, namespaces, stripe-payments

I have a problem of loading the same library twice for a wordpress plugin and theme.
The user wants to use both of these but they keep conflicting because the classes are already declared once.
So I need a way to use both using namespace and keep them both working.

The library  being used is Stripe,
[Stripe, github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

I'm trying since 2 days to get this done.
I am not very much familiar with namespaces. I read the php.net but can't see how to apply here.

The library also consists 'extends' and 'implements' keywords.
I hope someone can guide me so that I can accomplish this. 
Thanks.

Comment: `namespace`, `implement`, `interface` are too big concepts. can't be written down on one answer.

Comment: So isn't there a way to do this ?